# Excel VBA: Find cells with similar values

Tags: excel, vba

Another difficult task for me...

I have a excel sheet like this...

[image]

In the first column there are two `Aa`s, their values are shown in the second column, which is `A string` and `Astring`.

`A string` and `Astring` differ **only** from one blank key. I want to use excel VBA to say, these two values are equal, as long as they are same in the first column, but differ only from one letter in the second column. One of them should be deleted then. [shown in the "target" part]

Similarly, there are two `Dd`s, their values differ **only** from a `;`.

Here I wrote some code, but I dont know how to do the `if algorithmus`.

```
Sub deletesimilars()

    Dim lr As Long

    lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = lr To 1 Step -1  'reverse loop
       If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
'           if cells(i,2) ??? cells(i-1,2) then     ' I stuck here
                Cells(i, 1) = ""
                Cells(i, 2) = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: I realise that your example is (almost certainly) just an example, but if the two "Dd" values were switched would you want "A;number" to be the value kept with "A number" being removed?

Comment: @YowE3K It will be OK. The purpose of this VBA programm is to delete some duplicates with similarities. It will be OK if I have to change the values manually afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this previous in my work, when I want to guarantee the "equivalence" of certain string. So my technique is to "normalize" the strings by focusing on the important content of the string.

In most of my cases, this means:

- stripping all whitespace (usually not important anyway)
- converting everything to lowercase (case is often not important to me)
- sometimes ignoring certain special characters

So I have a utility function called `NormalizeString` that performs these actions.

Your code then becomes:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteSimilars()
    Dim thisSH As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Set thisSH = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = thisSH.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim i As Long
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If thisSH.Cells(i, 1) = thisSH.Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            If NormalizeString(thisSH.Cells(i, 2), ";") = _
               NormalizeString(thisSH.Cells(i - 1, 2), ";") Then
                thisSH.Cells(i, 1) = vbNullString
                thisSH.Cells(i, 2) = vbNullString
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function NormalizeString(ByVal inputStr As String, _
                         Optional ByVal specialChars As String) As String
    '--- "normalizes" a string by a series of modifications, such as
    '      -- removes all whitespace
    '      -- converts all characters to lowercase
    '      -- removes other "special" characters that should not
    '         be considered part of the string
    Dim returnString As String
    returnString = Replace(inputStr, " ", "", , , vbTextCompare)
    returnString = LCase(returnString)
    If Not IsMissing(specialChars) Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To Len(specialChars)
            returnString = Replace(returnString, _
                                   Mid(specialChars, i, 1), "", , , vbTextCompare)
        Next i
    End If
    NormalizeString = returnString
End Function
```